# Let $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of piecewise continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f_n$ uniformly converge to $f$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove or disprove that $f$ is piecewise continuous.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: If the sequence has in total finitely many discontinuities, then I can show that f is piecewise continuous by proving if fn is continuous at a, then f is continuous at a. But I don't know what would be the answer if the sequence has infinite discontinuities...

Comment: Strange things can happen. Wait a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q = ℚ ∩ [a..b]$ and $ν \colon ℕ → Q$ be an enumeration of $Q$, the set of rationals in $[a..b]$. Let $g_n = \mathbb{1}_{\{ν(n)\}}/n$ (i.e. the function which is $1/n$ at $ν(n)$ and vanishes elsewhere) and $f_n = Σ_{k=1}^n g_k$. Obviously, $(f_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}$ is a sequence of piecewise continuous functions which converge to
$$f \colon [a..b] → ℝ,\, x ↦ \begin{cases} 1/n \quad &\text{if $x = ν(n)$} \\ 0 \quad &\text{else} \end{cases},$$
which is discontinuous in all $Q$ and therefore not piecewise continuous. The convergence is uniformly as $|f - f_n|_∞ ≤ 1/n,\; ∀ n ∈ ℕ$.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks a lot!